# Converting loads on horizontal surfaces to inclined surfaces

Tags: free-body-diagram, statics

A textbook on design of wood structures makes the following argument:

[image: enter preformatted text here]

We have a flat roof snow load $$S_1 = 61.6 \frac{lb}{ft^2}$$. The idea is to convert it to an equivalent sloped roof snow load $S_2$ according to the following assumption,

"Snow loads acting on a sloping surface shall be assumed to act on the horizontal projection of that surface. "

And then superimpose it to the preexisting dead load $$D = 14 \frac{lb}{ft^2}$$

I do not agree, even based on the stated assumption, that the flat roof snow load should be any different from the sloped roof snow load. Gravity, as a vector, has constant direction and magnitude. The mass of the snow per unit area does not change. Why should the sloped roof snow load become less than the flat roof snow load? My argument is that:

$$Total Load = D+S_2 = (61.6+14)\frac{lb}{ft^2} = 75.6\frac{lb}{ft^2}$$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The author is talking about pressure with units pounds per square foot.  It looks like a flat roof which covers a given floor area is being compared with a pitched roof which covers the same floor area.  The pressure acting on the roof depends on the normal force acting on the roof.  So for a pitched roof it will be a component of the weight of the roof with the factor involved being the cosine of the angle of inclination which is the fraction in the bracket.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer. Your answer raises some interesting points but I realized that my question was unclear.

Comment: On a sloping roof there is a compressive load and a shear load.

Answer (score 0):

The design snow load for a sloped roof is determined by multiplying
the corresponding flat-roof snow load by a slope factor Cs. Thus,
ps = ¼ Cs pf
in which ps is the design sloped-roof snow load considered to act on the
horizontal projection of the roof surface, and the slope factor Cs is calculated by some formula.
The slope factors are based on the considerations
that more snow is likely to slide off of steep roofs, as compared to shallow
ones, and that more snow is likely to melt and slide off the roofs of
heated structures than those of unheated structures.

from theory of structures aslam kassimali